# Throwing exceptions with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I am joining 2 in memory collections

```
var items = 
    from el in elements 
    join def in Cached.Elements() 
        on el.Value equals def.Name into temp1
    from res in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()                        
    select new
    {
        el.NodeType, 
        res.DefKey, 
        res.DefType, 
        res.BaseKey, 
        el.Value 
    };
```

However, ideally if one of the elements can't be found, I'd like to raise an exception, something akin to

```
throw new System.Exception(el.Value + " cannot be found in cache!");
```

I was looking at the System.Interactive which offers a Catch extension method but I am unsure how to reference the current 'el' in that context. So for example I was wondering about something like

```
    var items = (
        from el in elements 
        join def in Cached.Elements() 
            on el.Value equals def.Name into temp1
        from res in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()                        
        select new 
        { 
            el.NodeType, 
            res.DefKey, 
            res.DefType, 
            res.BaseKey, 
            el.Value 
        })
        .ThrowIfEmpty();
```

but, istm, that that would entail passing the whole set into the extension method rather than raising the exception when the missing value is encountered.

Alternatively, I could replace the DefaultIfEmpty with a ThrowIfEmpty

```
    var items = (
        from el in elements 
        join def in Cached.Elements() 
            on el.Value equals def.Name into temp1
        from res in temp1.ThrowIfEmpty()                        
        select new 
        { 
            el.NodeType, 
            res.DefKey, 
            res.DefType, 
            res.BaseKey, 
            el.Value 
        });
```

Is there a 'proper'/better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GroupJoin. Something like this should work for you:

```
elements.GroupJoin(Cached.Elements(), e => e.Value, d => d.Name, (e, dSeq) => {
    var d = dSeq.Single();
    return new { e, d };
});
```

The GroupJoin resultSelector accepts two arguments: the left key, and the sequence of matching right keys. You can raise an exception if the sequence is empty; one way to achieve that would be to use the Single operator.

Comment: Thx very much Igor. Good pointer. A further q ... Am I right in thinking that you would be wrapping the linq statement in a try catch rather than throwing the exception in the context of the fluent interface (FWIW I've no qualms about, that just wanted to check)?

Comment: Sorry ... ok... the penny just dropped! Throw the exception from within the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of the places where you can use [Composite Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx).

if you use `equals` keyword to execute equality on join.

from documentation :

> You create a composite key as an anonymous type or named typed with
>   the values that you want to compare. If the query variable will be
>   passed across method boundaries, use a named type that overrides
>   Equals and GetHashCode for the key